# Can a list of beans be injected using Spring

Tags: java, spring-jms

I would like to create a list of JMS MessageProducer from one single connection. Each of these producers need to be created from a separate Session.

I would like to something like this in Spring but obviously this does not work.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
@Scope("prototype")
public Session jmsSession(final Connection jmsConnection) {
    <create a session>
}


@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public List<MessageProducer> jmsProvider(List<Session> jmsSessionList) {
    <Create a list of MessageProducers from the list of jmsSessionList>
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

1. Create a specific number of Sessions from one connection.(The number of sessions is a configuration property in yml file)
2. Inject the list of Session to another bean to create MessageProducer
3. Specify destroyMethod to destroy them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you intend.

1. For this you would need to create multiple `Session` beans as follows:

   ```java
   @Configuration
   class SessionsConfiguration {

     @Autowired
     private GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;

     @Value("${your.configuration.key}")
     private int sessionsCount;

     @PostConstruct
     fun init() {
       for (int i : sessionsCount) {
           applicationContext.registerBean() // Here you have multiple possibilities. 
           // Check reference documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Your code should already do this.
3. Your code should already do this.

Comment: Thanks. This is not what I intended to do. The number of session is a configuration property which may change from 2 - 10. So I need to dynamically create the sessions rather than hard code them.

Comment: That is possible. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Done. Please check it.